# Variable List Form Input Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I am creating a form that has a feature(s) input. It starts off with only 1 but the number may increase. By clicking on a button I will append a new text box for new feature to be written into it via Jquery.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmckeow/ewnetzqx/

Issue 1:error from java script saying that I cannot use input.attr().

Issue 2:When I do get this JavaScript to work, how am I supposed to reference a variable number of elements i.e. (feature1, feature2, feature3, ...) in PHP. When I submit a form with post I usually access the information in each element via it's name. How can I do that when I am not sure how many features there will be.

HTML:

```
    <div id="new_product">
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p>
        <label for="feature1"> Feature(s): </label>
        <input type="text" name="feature1" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_feature">Add Feature</button>
       <p> 
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
    var feature_count=1;
    var feature_count_old=0;
    $( "#add_feature" ).click(function() {
       feature_count_old=feature_count;
       feature_count+=1;
       var input = document.createElement("input");
       input.attr('name', 'feature' + feature_count);
       input.attr('type', 'text');
       $("input[name='feature'+feature_count_old]").after(input);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**
You did not load jQuery, so $ is not defined. Simply add the jQuery library to your snippet and you're good to go!

**Issue 2**
attr() is a jQuery method and not vanilla JS, so you need to do something like this:

```
var $input = $('input');
$input.attr('name', 'feature' + feature_count);
```